# C++ stream openmode combinations

Tags: c++, file-io, stream, iostream

How do the [C++ `std::ios_base::openmode` flags](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) work, and what do they do?

To be more specific:

- What are the valid combinations of `std::ios_base::openmode` for the various stream / filestream objects in the C++ standard library?
- What happens if a combination is incorrect?
- Do these combinations correspond to the various C-style strings passed as arguments to `fopen`: "rb", "r+" etc.? If so, which C++ `openmode` flags correspond to which C-style modes?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/fstream Be sure to only ask problems here.

Comment: I am aware of those classes. That link contains no further info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in [std::basic_filebuf::open](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open), the following are valid openmode combinations:

- `in`, equivalent of `"r"`
- `out`, equivalent of `"w"`
- `app`, equivalent of `"a"`
- `out|in`, equivalent of `"r+"`
- `out|in|trunc`, equivalent of `"w+"`
- `out|in|app`, equivalent of `"a+"`
- `binary|in`, equivalent of `"rb"`
- `binary|out`, equivalent of `"wb"`
- `binary|app`, equivalent of `"ab"`
- `binary|out|in`, equivalent of `"r+b"`
- `binary|out|in|trunc`, equivalent of `"w+b"`
- `binary|out|in|app`, equivalent of `"a+b"`

Any other combination will result in a failure.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll ask the other stuff in a separate question.

Comment: See table heading on the linked page: "openmode & ~ate"